# Npm update -package- does not update the package

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, npm

I am simply trying to update `webpack-dev-server` from version `3.11.2` to the latest version, which is `4.7.3` based on my `npm outdated` command:

```
root@fdaf6460fe1a:/home/ubuntu/myapp# npm outdated
Package               Current  Wanted  Latest  Location                           Depended by
@rails/activestorage    6.1.4   6.1.4   7.0.1  node_modules/@rails/activestorage  myapp
@rails/ujs              6.1.4   6.1.4   7.0.1  node_modules/@rails/ujs            myapp
@rails/webpacker        5.4.0   5.4.0   5.4.3  node_modules/@rails/webpacker      myapp
bootstrap               4.3.1   4.3.1   5.1.3  node_modules/bootstrap             myapp
datatables.net-bs4      3.2.2   3.2.2  1.11.4  node_modules/datatables.net-bs4    myapp
webpack                4.46.0  4.46.0  5.67.0  node_modules/webpack               myapp
webpack-cli            3.3.12  3.3.12   4.9.2  node_modules/webpack-cli           myapp
webpack-dev-server     3.11.2  3.11.2   4.7.3  node_modules/webpack-dev-server    myapp
```

However, whenever I run `npm update webpack-dev-server`, it seems to run but doesn't change the version:

```
root@fdaf6460fe1a:/home/ubuntu/myapp# npm update webpack-dev-server

up to date, audited 1312 packages in 3s

123 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

98 vulnerabilities (2 low, 88 moderate, 8 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

but when I run `npm list webpack-dev-server`, the version is still `3.11.2`:

```
root@fdaf6460fe1a:/home/ubuntu/myapp# npm list webpack-dev-server
app@1.0.0 /home/ubuntu/myapp
└── webpack-dev-server@3.11.2
```

In my `package.json` file, it does list `webpack-dev-server` in the following manner:

```
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
```

However, I've tried removing the `^` and running `npm update webpack-dev-server` again still, but no luck. How exactly do I update `webpack-dev-server` in my case or figure out why it's not updating?

How do I even know that `npm update` is even working? I can run `npm update <anything here>` and it doesn't return any errors:

```
root@fdaf6460fe1a:/home/ubuntu/myapp# npm update npmkerjhtekrhjter

up to date, audited 1312 packages in 3s
```

Answer (score 3):

`npm update` will only update to whatever is specified in your `package.json`. Removing the `^` doesn't make it more lax. It makes it more strict.

To update to 4.x:  `npm install webpack-dev-server@4`

That will install the 4.x version and update `package.json` (and `package-lock.json` if you're using that).

In your case, `npm udpate` isn't going to do anything because all the versions in the `Current` column are the same as the `Wanted` column. The `Wanted` column is what `npm update` will update to, but there's nothing to update. The `Latest` column lets you know if there are newer versions than what your `package.json` permits.